# Groom's birth place entry additions

Tags: palaeography, marriage-records, austria, parish-register

I have a [marriage entry](https://www.crarc.findbuch.net/php/view.php?link=4f657374612d572d4653x11#&path=de6cd06cdec76bf7db366efdd0c76bf7d5d5c76bf7d5d5e1edeaecea6be1ecc5ecedc76bf7d5d5e1edeaecea6be1ecc5eced6be0e4eaee6be0e4eae36be1ecc56dfc30f6f6373f6beeede3c7d961df) here of someone (Edmund Hoffmeister von Hoffenegg) with birth place listed as Andrijevci in present day Croatia but then for some reason also mentions Klattau (Klatovy) in Bohemia:

[image: Edmund Hoffmeister von Hoffenegg birth place, Feldsuperiorat Wien, 02-24 (1893-1896), f. 328]

Why is the second place mentioned? Is this where he grew up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I read

> Andrievci, Kreis Brod in Slawonien
>   heimatszuständig nach Klattau gl. Bez. in Böhmen

The answer to your question lies in "heimatzuständig" or also only "zuständig" (responsible) in other records. The "Heimatrecht" (local citizenship) in a community was acquired either by being born there, marrying in or in later days also by living there for a certain amount of time. See [Heimatrecht](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heimatrecht) on Wikipedia for details.

The local citizenship had some legal implications e.g. if you would become that poor/ill/old and could no longer earn your food then the community where you lived would look after you, but if they couldn't or refused (I'm not sure on the details.) then your home community would have to care for you.

Comment: Thank you, very nice answer with this detailed explanation!
Does that mean that he had he had the Heimatrecht in Klattau at the time of marriage (e.g. because he was living there and/or because his previous marriage was there)?

Comment: Since he was widower it could be that he married there or lived there longer. He was born apparently in "Andrievci".

Comment: Heimatrecht could essentially be inherited, as in, he may have "belonged" in Klattau because one or both of his parents were born there.